# Get path traveled from a given starting node

Tags: java, algorithm

I have some nodes that are connected with the distance between nodes fixed as 1.

The nodes represent cities, so I have from cities and to cities where I can travel. Also a starting node.

The nodes are connected bi-directional.

Now, I want to find the order of travel from the starting node to the next closest node, if nodes are at the same distance, then select the node based on priority.

**Example:**

```
from = [1,1,2, 3,1], to = [2,3,4,5,5]

starting node = 1
```

The graph looks like this:

```
4
|
|
2
|
|
1 -- 3
|   /
|/  
5
```

So I will travel like this from 1 ::: **2 --> 3 --> 5 --> 4**

**Explanation:**
From 1 the nodes 2,5,3 are at a fixed distance of 1 and node 4 is at distance 2. If we sort  2,5,3  we get 2,3,5. So First we reach 2,3,5 then 4.

How to implement this in Java, if my method is like:

```
static List<Integer> process(int nodeCount, List<Integer> from, List<Integer> to, int startingnode) {

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < from.size(); i++) {
        int frm = from.get(i);
        int tov = to.get(i);
        List<Integer> a = map.getOrDefault(frm, new ArrayList<>());
        List<Integer> b = map.getOrDefault(tov, new ArrayList<>());
        a.add(tov);
        b.add(frm);
        map.put(frm, a);
        map.put(tov, b);
    }

    System.out.println(map);
    List<Integer> a = map.get(startingnode);
    a.sort(null);
    System.out.println(a);
    //a.add(startingnode);
    //map.keySet().removeAll(a);
    //System.out.println(map);
    return null;

}
```

Here I tried , but I am able to get the nodes located at distance 1. But I am stuck on how to read the other nodes. I am using a hash map to store the nodes.

Comment: Is your goal, sorting with nearest to farthest nodes and if any nodes distance the same sort with ascending, right?

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz, yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I didn't realize the construct of the graph in the form of from/to
we will need BFS as follows,

```java
    public String bfs(int v, int N, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList) {
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(v);
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> orderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        int[] distance = new int[N];
        Arrays.fill(distance, 0); // 0 signifies unvisited
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            int r = q.poll();
            for (int s : adjList.getOrDefault(r, new ArrayList<>())) {
                if (distance[s] == 0) {
                    q.add(s);
                    distance[s] = distance[r] + 1;
                    // add the node to the map at appropriate level
                    Set<Integer> myLevel =
                         orderMap.getOrDefault(distance[r] + 1, new TreeSet<>());
                    myLevel.add(s);
                    orderMap.put(distance[r] + 1, myLevel);
                }
            }
        }
        return Arrays.toString(
               orderMap.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).toArray());
    }

   /**
     * graph is an adjacency list representation.
     * We need parameter N, so that we can store the vertices 
     * in an array with appropriate indexes. 
     * We make N one more than your total vertices since arrays are with 0-indexed
     */
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<>();
        //[1,1,2, 3,1], to = [2,3,4,5,5]
        List<Integer> ones = List.of(2, 3, 5);
        List<Integer> two = List.of(4);
        List<Integer> three = List.of(5);
        adjList.put(1, ones);
        adjList.put(2, two);
        adjList.put(3, three);
        System.out.println(bfs(1, 6,adjList ));
    }
```

I am using TreeSet so that we can sort the numbers as you wanted.

Comment: My input contains only arrays. But here I see TreeNode, how to get that from arrays? can you please help in that.

Comment: Also, I see root.left, root.right, I don't have such nodes in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a modified `Dijkstra` algorithm for your case. There is an excellent implementation [Dijkstra Shortest Path Algorithm in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dijkstra).
`Node` class have `distance` and adjacent list for calculating distances.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Node {
    private Integer value;
    private Integer distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private Set<Node> adjacentNodes = new HashSet<>();

    public Node(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void addAdjacent(Node other) {
        adjacentNodes.add(other);
    }

    public Integer getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Integer distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public Set<Node> getAdjacentNodes() {
        return adjacentNodes;
    }
}
```

Main class

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> from = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 1);
        List<Integer> to = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 5);

        List<Integer> result = process(5, from, to, 1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static List<Integer> process(int nodeCount, List<Integer> from, List<Integer> to, int startingNode) {
        // create a nodes map with value
        Map<Integer, Node> nodesMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= nodeCount; i++) {
            nodesMap.put(i, new Node(i));
        }

        // initialize bi-directional adjacent lists
        for (int i = 0; i < from.size(); i++) {
            Node nodeFrom = nodesMap.get(from.get(i));
            Node nodeTo = nodesMap.get(to.get(i));
            nodeFrom.addAdjacent(nodeTo);
            nodeTo.addAdjacent(nodeFrom);
        }

        // starting node
        Node startNode = nodesMap.get(startingNode);
        startNode.setDistance(0);

        // visited nodes
        List<Node> visitedNodes = new ArrayList<>();

        // waiting to visit nodes
        LinkedList<Node> waitingNodes = new LinkedList<>();

        // push current start node
        waitingNodes.push(startNode);

        // loop until waiting list is empty
        while (!waitingNodes.isEmpty()) {
            // remove from waiting nodes list
            Node currentNode = waitingNodes.pop();

            // add into visited list
            visitedNodes.add(currentNode);

            // new distance is currentNode.distance + 1
            int newDistance = currentNode.getDistance() + 1;

            // get adjacent list
            for (Node adjacentNode : currentNode.getAdjacentNodes()) {
                if (newDistance < adjacentNode.getDistance()) {
                    // update adjacent distance
                    adjacentNode.setDistance(newDistance);

                    // if adjacent node is not visited add into waiting nodes
                    if (!visitedNodes.contains(adjacentNode)) {
                        waitingNodes.push(adjacentNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<Integer> sortedList = nodesMap.values()
                .stream()
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> {
                    // if distances are equal, compare with value
                    if (o1.getDistance().equals(o2.getDistance())) {
                        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                    }
                    // compare with distance
                    return o1.getDistance().compareTo(o2.getDistance());
                })
                .map(Node::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return sortedList;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```